# Please help me to find answer for some SQL questions

Tags: sql-server

I have few questions which i have been asked in interview:

1. Performance difference between delete and truncate?
2. Delete duplicate data from a table which is not having any id column and should not use CTE.
3. Why we are able to delete data using CTE?

Answer (score 4):

1. `DELETE` logs each individual deletion, whereas `TRUNCATE` is a bulk logged operation, hence is faster.
2. You could `SELECT DISTINCT` data into a temp table, `TRUNCATE` the first then reinsert.
3. Not a scooby...

Answer (score 1):

here are some pointers to solve your issues:

1. Since TRUNCATE doesn't actually delete data, but deallocate the data by removing pointers to the indexes it will be much faster than DELETE, when you use DELETE everything is stored in the transaction log row by row, hence it's much slower.
2. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/159881/How-to-remove-duplicate-rows-in-SQL-Server-2008-wh
3. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/23/sql-server-2005-2008-delete-duplicate-rows/

Comment: The 2nd link which you have given performs the delete operation using CTE .Op wants to delete the data without using CTE